# C# maintaining HasChanged for class of list properties

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core, object

I am converting my code from datasets to list of class objects. For checking if any value in list is of object is modified or added or deleted, I am using object tracking technique.

My code is as follows:

**VendorInvoiceData Model:**

```cs
public class VendorInvoiceData
{
    public VendorInvoiceData() { }
    
    public VendorInvoiceData(VendorInvoiceData vendorInvoiceData)
    {
        VendorInvoiceDataId = vendorInvoiceData.VendorInvoiceDataId;
        VendorInvoiceId = vendorInvoiceData.VendorInvoiceId;
        ChargeId = vendorInvoiceData.ChargeId;
        ChargeCode = vendorInvoiceData.ChargeCode;
        InvoiceAmount = vendorInvoiceData.InvoiceAmount;
        CreatedBy = vendorInvoiceData.CreatedBy;
        CreationDate = vendorInvoiceData.CreationDate;
        SpreadGroup = vendorInvoiceData.SpreadGroup;
        SpreadOrder = vendorInvoiceData.SpreadOrder;
    }

    public int VendorInvoiceDataId { get; set; }
    public int? VendorInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int? ChargeId { get; set; }
    public string ChargeCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string SpreadGroup { get; set; }
    public short? SpreadOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**VendorInvoiceStatusLog Model:**

```cs
public class VendorInvoiceStatusLog
{
    public VendorInvoiceStatusLog() { }

    public VendorInvoiceStatusLog(VendorInvoiceStatusLog vendorInvoiceStatusLog)
    {
        VendorInvoiceStatusLogId = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.VendorInvoiceStatusLogId;
        VendorInvoiceId = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.VendorInvoiceId;
        VendorInvoiceStatus = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.VendorInvoiceStatus;
        VendorInvoiceStatusDescription = 
        vendorInvoiceStatusLog.VendorInvoiceStatusDescription;
        CreatedBy = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.CreatedBy;
        CreationDate = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.CreationDate;
        IsAdded = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.IsAdded;
        IsUpdated = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.IsUpdated;
        IsDeleted = vendorInvoiceStatusLog.IsDeleted;
    }

    public int VendorInvoiceStatusLogId { get; set; }
    public int? VendorInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string VendorInvoiceStatus { get; set; }
    public string VendorInvoiceStatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdded { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsUpdated { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

**VendorInvoiceModelsList Model:**

```cs
public class VendorInvoiceModelsList
{
    public List<VendorInvoiceStatusLog> VendorInvoiceStatusLogList { get; set; }
    public List<VendorInvoiceData> VendorInvoiceDataList { get; set; }

    public VendorInvoiceModelsList originalState;

    public void SetOriginalState()
    {
        originalState = new VendorInvoiceModelsList
        {
            VendorInvoiceStatusLogList = VendorInvoiceStatusLogList.Select(x => new VendorInvoiceStatusLog(x)).ToList(),
            VendorInvoiceDataList = VendorInvoiceDataList.Select(x => new VendorInvoiceData(x)).ToList(),
        };
    }

    public bool HasChanged()
    {
        if (originalState == null) return false;

        bool statusLog = !VendorInvoiceStatusLogList.SequenceEqual(originalState.VendorInvoiceStatusLogList);
        bool data = !VendorInvoiceDataList.SequenceEqual(originalState.VendorInvoiceDataList);

        return statusLog || data;
    }
}
```

**Now, using above code:**

```cs
VendorInvoiceModelsList vendorInvoiceModels = Find(vendorInvoiceId);
vendorInvoiceModels .SetOriginalState();
var data = vendorInvoiceModels.HasChanged(); // returns true
vendorInvoiceModels.VendorInvoiceList[0].VendorInvoiceStatus = "newStatus";
var data1 = vendorInvoiceModels.HasChanged(); // returns true
```

`Datatable` maintain `HasChange` method, which I want to implement in my code because of the requirement.
From above code, `data` variable should be `false` and `data1` variable should be `true`.

I checked my code multiple times, but it keeps returning wrong Boolean value. I have even checked data returning from `vendorInvoiceModels` object and compared the object values with `originalState` object. They have the same values. I don't why `HasChange` method is returning wrong value.

Comment: Your object should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then you just watch for the event to fire and set `HasCHanged`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't want to use INotifyPropertyChanged. How can I achieve the same with my code

Comment: You need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` if you want your code to correctly compute when you do `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Can you please tell me how can I do it with above code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to allow comparisons of your objects:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is VendorInvoiceData other)
    {
        return
            this.VendorInvoiceDataId.Equals(other.VendorInvoiceDataId)
            && this.VendorInvoiceId.Equals(other.VendorInvoiceId)
            && this.ChargeId.Equals(other.ChargeId)
            && this.ChargeCode.Equals(other.ChargeCode)
            && this.InvoiceAmount.Equals(other.InvoiceAmount)
            && this.CreatedBy.Equals(other.CreatedBy)
            && this.CreationDate.Equals(other.CreationDate)
            && this.SpreadGroup.Equals(other.SpreadGroup)
            && this.SpreadOrder.Equals(other.SpreadOrder);
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public override int GetHashCode() =>
    this.VendorInvoiceDataId.GetHashCode()
    ^ this.VendorInvoiceId?.GetHashCode() ?? 0
    ^ this.ChargeId?.GetHashCode() ?? 0
    ^ this.ChargeCode.GetHashCode()
    ^ this.InvoiceAmount?.GetHashCode() ?? 0
    ^ this.CreatedBy.GetHashCode()
    ^ this.CreationDate?.GetHashCode() ?? 0
    ^ this.SpreadGroup.GetHashCode()
    ^ this.SpreadOrder?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
```

Comment: this code is not working

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - Sorry, I forgot to compile before posting.